# Is it possible to use Google Chrome profiles for parallel testing?

Tags: multithreading, profile, autotest

I have one logged-in profile, and each test has to use that profile to start and run the test at the same time.

`ConfigReader configReader = ConfigReader.getInstance(); System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", configReader.getChromedriverPath()); System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.bin", configReader.getChromeBrowser()); ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User    Data/Default/Default"); driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`

I've received errors, so I can start the session and pass just the first test. Others failed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but we need to create and use as many profiles as there are threads.